# Phalcon PHP extend and override "update" and "insert" functions

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, phalcon

I would like to implement my own database dialect in Phalcon PHP. I would like to extend and override few functions that are already reserved for PDO. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class DB extends \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql{
    function _construct($connection_variables=array())
    {
        parent::_construct($connection_variables);
    }

    function update($table="",$variables="")
    {
        parent::execute($query);
    }
}
```

So, when I try to to call in the model:

```
$this->db->update('test',array('id'=>'1'));
```

It gives me an error stating that:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Libraries\DB::update() must be compatible with Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface::update($table, $fields, $values, $whereCondition = NULL, $dataTypes = NULL) in .....
```

How can I override update and insert functions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update` method must match with the method declared in the `Phalcon\Db\AdapterInterface` interface, it should be:

```
function update($table, $fields, $values, $whereCondition = NULL, $dataTypes = NULL)
{
    // ...
}
```

Instead of:

```
function update($table="",$variables="")
{
    // ...
}
```

The method `signature/header` must be the same as it is in the `interface`.

Comment: But I want to have a custom update function. In Phalcon, for some reason you need to have fields in array separate from values - which is not pretty. I want to pass values as associative array ('field1'=>'value1','field2'=>'value2'), like in CodeIgniter. Is there a way to do that by extending the class?

Comment: In this case you can't use same method with a different signature, you must use same method declaration or otherwise use a different one.

Comment: Thank you! It seems I will need to be creative with the method naming.

Comment: Well, this is the nature of an [interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), you are welcome :-)